# How do I find the area of the shaded region between $y=3x^2$ and $y=24-6x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

So first off, I know that I have:
$y=3x^2$ and $y=24-6x$

Do I first set these equations equal to each other? If so, then I get:
$(3x^2)+6x-24=0$.

Therefore, I would get $x=-4$ or $x=-2$

Is this correct so far?

If so, then I know I would put these numbers over and below the integral symbol.

If all of this is correct so far, then my biggest question is this; How do I know which numbers to put above and below the integral symbol, and how do I know what equation to put into the integral function part, in order to take the anti derivative and find the area?

**Disclaimer:** I am new to this online community, and so if you see something in my question/post that should not belong, or that you do not like, please tell me before down-voting my post. I am not trying to get someone to strictly do homework for me. I am trying to learn so that I can replicate it on similar problems. I want to be respectful. My class is online, so asking specific questions in class is a challenge, as there are no interactive lectures.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $y=12$ on the y-axis?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't solve the quadratic equation correctly: $3x^2=24-6x$ gives you $x=-4$ or $x=2$. Then you can check that the two curves meet at $(2,12)$.

In general, the definite integral $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx$ gives you the area of the region under the curve provided by $y=f(x)$. Here, you have $a=0$, $b=4$ and 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
3x^2,& 0\leqslant x\leqslant 2,\\
24-6x, & 2\leqslant x\leqslant 4.
\end{cases}
$$
Remember that integration is "additive":
$$
\int_{a}^bf(x)\ dx = \int_a^cf(x)\ dx+\int_c^bf(x)\ dx.
$$
Here you have $c=2$.

Answer (score 0):

We already know that area of a rectangle is the product of it's sides. Now using the same approach we draw two stripes of Differential (infinitesimally small) thickness $dx$ and $dy$. Look at the below image (please excuse the bad image quality).

[image: image with differential strips]

Now as you can see in the picture there is a mini rectangle formed by the intersection of those stripes and the dimensions of the rectangle is $dx$ and $dy$. Hence we can the area of the differential rectangle is $dA=dxdy$. So now we the area of the differential rectangle also called the differential area and all we have to do is move the strips from one extreme (limit) to the other so that we can get the area of all other rectangles and add them.

Because we are moving both the strips and we have two differential lengths $dx$ and $dy$, we have to do double integration to integrate the area by one strip ($dx$) from left to right and the other strip ($dy$) from down to top. Hence we have :

$A=\begin{align*}\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}\int_{y_{1}}^{y_{2}}dA \end{align*}$

Now all we have to do is figure out the limits. As mentioned by @user587192 your point of cutoff is $(2,12)$. The function varies for different $x$. So we cannot apply the above formulae directly as the function $y$ changes after a certain $x$. Hence we break it off at $c=2$.

$A=\begin{align*}\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}\int_{y_{1}}^{y_{2}}dA =\int_{x_{1}}^{c}\int_{y_{1}}^{y_{2a}}dA + \int_{c}^{x_{2}}\int_{y_{1}}^{y_{2b}}dA \end{align*}$

$y_{2a}$ and $y_{2b}$ are different functions before and after the breakoff point $c$. So finally it becomes-

$A=\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{3x^2}dydx + \int_{2}^{4}\int_{0}^{24-6x}dydx \end{align*}$

Which ultimately becomes-

$A=\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{2}3x^{2}dx + \int_{2}^{4}(24-6x)dx. \end{align*}$

I hope you understand it better now.